# Consulta con LEFT

Tags: sql

Tengo una duda, estoy tratando de hacer una consulta que primero busque un determinado número en un rango de números y una vez que encuentre la fila compare el campo NIR con el resultado de una condición: si el número empieza con 33 me dará los primeros 2 dígitos si no me entrega los primeros 3. Mi consulta es la siguiente, sin embargo al parecer la sintaxis esta mal, e intentado varias cosas e incluso poner un if pero no logro que funcione.

```
Select * from pnn_Publico where '3328570050' 
  BETWEEN Numeracion_Inicial AND Numeracion_Final and 
  NIR = (select(left ('3328570005',2)) where '3328570005' LIKE '33%') 
  or (select (left ('3328570005',3))
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda y tiempo prestado.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo lo que haria para simplificar el query seria utilizar dos AND unidos por un AND en vez de los selects quedaria algo asi:

```sql
Select * from pnn_Publico where '3328570050' 
  BETWEEN Numeracion_Inicial AND Numeracion_Final and 
  (
    ( NIR = left ('3328570005',2) AND '3328570005' LIKE '33%')
    or
    ( NIR = left ('3328570005',3) )
```

Comment: Lo siento soy principiante y tu consulta me manda este error:                        
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')'.                                                                                            Busque y dice que es un error cerca del ) pero aun no se por que, serias tan amable de apoyarme. Gracias

Comment: falta un parentesis al final, se me habra borrado sin querer

Answer (score 0):

Esta es otra posible manera de hacerlo :

```
    select case when substring (CodigoNumerico, 1,2) = '33' then substring (CodigoNumerico, 1,2) 
                else  substring (CodigoNumerico, 1,3) end CodigoInicial     
    from
    (       
        select CodigoNumerico             
        from
        (
                      select '3366686180'   CodigoNumerico
            union all select '3801595760'
            union all select '3570773974'
            union all select '3921286625'
            union all select '3333341364'
            union all select '3328570050'
            union all select '3429743091'
            union all select '3804070169'
            union all select '3670088179'
            union all select '3928552613'
            union all select '3613520256'
        )c
        where CodigoNumerico  between '3328570050' and '3629743091'
    )D
    where CodigoNumerico = '3328570050'
```